# I will introduce you to my wife and children, what family am I?

Tags: computer-puzzle

> My family is building trust (<>.<>)

---

> **Hint 2**: Trust is related to adjective, but i suggest trying the others first and then the adjective.

---

> I have three meaningful children :3

---

> **Hint 1**. They all have different age. 
>
>  **Hint 1.5** They could, however, has the same size, face, etc (identical)

---

> Parents (mom/dad) always stay beside each children <3

---

> However, I often change my children if I don't like them! :(

---

> I also often change my children with better ones :D

---

> These are common response to my children:
>
> - We know it's gonna break :D
> - We thought it wouldn't break :D
> - Wow! Who knew that would break. :(

---

**What is the name of our family ( Mom & Dad & Children )**

---

> **Hint 3**: Its not that complex.. its barely programming specific. even a gamer, **for example** Minecraft player, probably familiar with 'my family', yet they might not figure out the puzzle. The point is you do see 'my family' in daily basis.

---

> **Hint 4**: My family is the digital / modern successor of a family that usually appear in dictionary cover. However, the older family is not helpful, instead they try to appear trendy. (Who the hell use that 7 cm thick dictionary nowadays..)

Comment: There is one answer. Answer is one word. Not from Math text book. And Yes its a puzzle.. sadly tag must be included..

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE. One simple question, is the smiley in almost every line there to show your poetic skills or pointing towards something subtle (in simple terms hints) ;D

Comment: The children part is hint the other were to to make the children part less visible but whatever.. its not hidden anymore is it?

Comment: Or maybe I lied. I actually accidentally make some of them a small hint

Comment: Ok, please read [this question to decide when to give hints](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5005/1766). Also, when you get time, do visit [a tour of the puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Yep no hints is also fine

Comment: this is a nice therapy for sleeping. you can sleep with an evil smile.. (i mean the puzzling.se

Comment: is this too hard?

Comment: If there were no `computer-puzzle` tag, I'd said 'smileys'.

Comment: I really don't want to self answer this.. maybe few more weeks, folks?

Comment: Do we need to know what minecraft is? I am more familiar with minesweeper.

Comment: no u dont need to know what mincraft is.. its just example on the level of 'everydayness' of 'my family'. An edit is made to clarify.

Comment: I will add a hint about my ancesstor (old pops) of my family.. next week?

Comment: hint 4 is very obvious... not much in dictionary cover, isn't it?

Comment: Why are the hints out in the open?

Comment: Is it not right?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment and i am unaware on if guessing is acceptable but i want to try, if this is wrong or bad practice i will remove answer.

You are a

> Tag, there are certain techniques with Parent Child elements in HTML.
>  Always start and end with <>.<>.
>  Can use line breaks.

Comment: Guessing is welcomed here! But typically for puzzles like this we'd encourage you to give a line-by-line explanation for how your answer fits with the clues.

Comment: @MarkPeters Noted, i suppose reading back at my answer it was a bit of a long shot. Nevertheless, I will keep it and hope that others may be inspired

Comment: No i have 3 children and mom OR OR AND (or we could say parents instead of and or grammar issue) dad beside each children.. there is one dad and one mommy..

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of your family be...

> The programming language PHP? Seems to me that at least it is a programming language of some sort. The parents seems to be the opening or closing tags the children are either functions or variables.

Comment: Its not that complex.. its barely programming specific. even minecraft player probably familiar with this.